# Code review for a specific piece of code

Tags: discussion, scope

I know the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and posted a question there. Would gis.se be a place for gis code review? I mean, can someone pop in, and asks: can you review some piece of my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, because that would run afoul of

https://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions **based on actual problems that you face**

If you have *functioning* code you don't really have a problem, do you?

Code review is for functioning code that you think can be made better in some indeterminate, abstract way: aesthetically, speed, layout, etc.